# Compilng different .cpp files with headers

Tags: c++, header, g++

I have a problem 
I am trying to compile multiple files together using GNU g++

We assume there are five files:

```
main.cpp : the main function 
a.h      : the header file of class A 
a.cpp    : the definition of class A 
b.h      : the header file of class B 
b.cpp    : the definition of class B
```

In the program, main.cpp uses class A (thus including a.h) and class A uses 
class B (thus including b.h).

So in my main I have just added #include "a.h"

and I am trying to compile it using

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

But this doesnt work. It gives me an "undefined reference to" error.
The program gives me the required output though when I compile all the classes together with the header file

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: Don't even *think* about `#include`-ing one .cpp file in another. Just telling you ahead of time. If you find yourself thinking its a good idea, think again. Then see the answers below.

Comment: There is no reason to put only one class in a header file. A header file can (and often should) contain several related declarations (of classes, functions, etc...) and inlined function definitions. For a small project like yours, it could make sense to have only one single header file (which you could pre-compile). You can have less `*.h` files than `*.cpp` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compile *all* of the source files:

```
g++ main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp -o main
```

If you want to do it in steps, you can do that too:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o  # compile
g++ -c a.cpp -o a.o        # compile
g++ -c b.cpp -o b.o        # compile
g++ -o main main.o a.o b.o # link
```

But what you *should* be doing is using a proper makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -MMD
OBJECTS = main.o a.o b.o
MAKEDEPS = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.d *.o main

.PHONY: clean

-include $(MAKEDEPS)
```

Example:

```
$ make
c++ -MMD   -c -o main.o main.cpp
c++ -MMD   -c -o a.o a.cpp
c++ -MMD   -c -o b.o b.cpp
c++ -MMD -o main main.o a.o b.o
```

Comment: @user2803194 - It is so that they know about each other

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; the headers are included by your source files, right?

Comment: The header files only contain the declarations of your class. All of the implementation lies in the .cpp files (this needn't be true always). By including the header files, you avoid the **compiler** error: "Variable abc and function xyz weren't declared"

Comment: @user2803194 Modularity. Headers contain the declarations of structure and functional provision; the .cpp files contain the actual implementations of the latter (as well as local declarations if they are not needed outside the .cpp file). The headers are the "conduit" by which one .cpp file "knows" what is offered up by another, and correctly utilizes that offering. But the implementations requiring linking together to make that a reality.

Comment: @CarlNorum: you forgot to put `-Wall -g` in your `CXXFLAGS` (in addition of `-MMD`)!

Answer (score 2):

When you build only `main.cpp`, the compiler doesn't complain because it finds the declarations of the objects and functions you call.
The linkers job is to ensure it can find the definitions.

Since you didn't ask to compile & link `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` along with `main.cpp`, you get the "undefined refrence to" error.

The linker is essentially telling you: "Hey, I can't find the definitions for so-and-so functions. The compiler didn't complain since you included the header file which had the declarations."

**Edit**: After seeing your comment, I can understand your problem. There is a difference between ***declaration*** and ***definition***.

The **compiler relies of finding declarations** to classes, functions, types and variables used. If you didn't include the header file (try it!), you'd get an *Undeclared identifier error* which is from the compiler.

The **linker relies on finding definitions** for functions and variables that you use. If you didn't link the required files containing the implementation/definitions, you'd get an *Undefined reference to ...* error, which is from the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Please read http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++

You need to compile with -c then link those objects